# not /n in scanf but program still waits

Tags: scanf

I've read on here that the /n in scanf makes the program wait for another input. my program however does not have a /n in scanf but it still waits for another input after i enter a number. Not sure why.

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int inputNumber, index = 2, lowestPrime = 1, number = 1;

printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &inputNumber);

if(scanf("%d", &inputNumber) != 1)
{ 
    printf("Invalid input");
    return 1;
}    
else
{
    printf(" The prime factorization of %d is",inputNumber);

    while(inputNumber > lowestPrime)
    { 
        if(inputNumber % index != 0)
        {
            index += 1;
        }   
        else
        {
            inputNumber = (inputNumber / index);
            printf(" %d", index);
        }
    }
} 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling scanf twice here, once for the original call and once in your if statement. Replace the statement inside the if parenthesis by

```
if (inputNumber!= 1)
```

and you should be fine!